# how to add the sub module code to my current repository?

Tags: git, gitlab

I use `git submodule add` to add a repo1 to my current repo0.

A new directory named repo1 was added to my repo0.

But I can't find any code in this directory.

How can I download all code in repo1 to my repo0?

Can anyone give me some help? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try first:

```sh
git config submodule.active .
git submodule update --init --remote
```

To see if that get more code.

Check also the content of the `.gitmodules` created after your `git submodule add <url/remote/repo>`.